# Where IN SUBSTR IF Statement

Tags: if-statement, where-clause, substr

I have numbers in a barcode scanner that are adding digits to the front and end of an entry

I'm trying to query to give me the first 8 -> 24 digits of the entry

```
where xx.tracking_id in ('&First_Tracking','&Second_Tracking','&Third_Tracking','&Fourth_Tracking','&Fifth_Tracking')
```

So if I scan the barcode XXXXXXX1234567890111222YYYYY only query on 1234567890111222 for the scan.

Also I only want  this to happen for when my name is Tiki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, YouTube need to use SUBSTRING function: `SUBSTRING(value, start, length)`

So in your case, it should be something like that

```sql
SELECT barecode FROM mytable
WHERE SUBSTRING(barecode, 8, 16) = '1234567890111222'
```

> Also I only this to happen for when my name is Tiki

Just need to add another clause in the where

```sql
SELECT barecode FROM mytable
WHERE SUBSTRING(barecode, 8, 16) = '1234567890111222' AND name = 'Tiki'
```

Comment: Thanks DonKnacki, are you saying to use barcode to define the number and use the SUBSTR function on that value? How would this work if I need to make multiple values?

Comment: If you consider that my answer solves your problem, please validate it

Comment: I had to leave for the day and I'm going to incorporate it in the code now will update ASAP

Comment: I don't think this is going to work because there are 5 values that are required so I think I'm going to need an IN statement. I'm trying to do this with multiple values.

Comment: That actually worked, thank you very much DONKNACKI!